# Alternative to returning pointer or reference to private member

Tags: c++

I often see people returning pointers or references to private members, which I've been told is bad practice (I've been guilt of doing this myself). What kind of poor design decisions lead to this, and what safe alternatives are there, if any?

Comment: It's not always bad practice. For example, many containers have methods that return internal pointers/references. It really depends on the situation and the particular code in question. I think this question is too broad without a concrete example you'd like to discuss.

Comment: Are you referring to `const` references?  Or mutable references?

Comment: Perhaps return a copy?

Comment: Well, a safe alternative (assuming doing so was unsafe in the first place) is to *not* return a pointer or a reference to a private member.

Comment: Your question is far too vague,"I often see people returning pointers or references to private members, which I've been told is bad practice" if you think whoever told you that meant it as broadly as you imply, then suggest finding further explanation from them, if they really did mean it so broadly, then I suggest you ignore their notion of "bad practice".

Comment: Not allays true. Few Design patterns return publicly reference to private elements (singleton and few more). Core is "scenario" of returning refference

Comment: It can be indicative of poor encapsulation. Ideally, your object should not look like its internals from the outside. Ideally you should act on the object and react to the object without knowing or caring what its internal members are. As with all rules there are always exceptions and people will happily argue over what should and what should not constitute an exception.

Comment: You might be interested by https://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html

Answer (score 2):

Returning a reference to private members is a bad idea only when the reference is mutable. This presents a problem, because callers obtain means for modifying the state of your object, bypassing any consistency checks that you may have in place.

Although returning a `const` reference does not expose you to the same problem, it is still not ideal, because the lifetime of the object that you returned is controlled by your object. If you decide to de-allocate the member while the caller still has a reference to it, you may cause undefined behavior in the caller.

A viable alternative to returning a reference is returning copies. This works reasonably well for small objects, but for larger objects it is still problematic. You could return a `const` reference with clear explanations of its lifetime, or return a smart pointer.